# JTable remove value from same value columns next to each other

Tags: java, swing, jtable

In a JTable, how can I detect all cells in a row in a DefaultTableCellRenderer's `getTableCellRendererComponent` that are next to each other and have the same value? I need to then remove said value from all but the center one.. I tried

```
if(table.getValueAt(row, column-1) == value && table.getValueAt(row, column+1) == value) {
    setValue("K")
}
```

to make sure I can atleast detect the center, but this works only when 3 cells have the same value.. I need more

Comment: Your problem is that you change the value before testing the other cells, so the condition isn't triggered after.

Comment: `How about doing this in a DefaultTableCellRenderer's` - no. A Renderer is for displaying the data in a cell. A Renderer is not used for processing logic. Your question doesn't have enough information. For example how many columns of data are there? What happens if you have 5 columns in a row with the same value? What about 4 columns. When do you do this check, when the data it loaded? Can the data be changed?

Comment: @camickr where should I put it then?

Comment: @RandoHinn, I have absolutely no idea. As I already told you I don't understand your requirement and you have not provided any additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over the entire row and check that each is the same as the value you want:

```
boolean same = true;
for (int col = 0; col < columnCount; col++) {
    if (table.getValueAt(row, col ) != value) {
         same = false;
         break;
    }
}
if (same) {
    setValue("K");
}
```

Comment: How about doing this in a DefaultTableCellRenderer's overriden `getTableCellRendererComponent`? edited the op to specify this..

Comment: `How about doing this in a DefaultTableCellRenderer's` - no. A Renderer is for displaying the data in a cell. A Renderer is not used for processing logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(table.getValueAt(row, column-1) == value && table.getValueAt(row, column+1) == value) {
    //add this
    for (int i = column; table.getValueAt(row, i) == value; i++)
        setValue("K");
}
```

You were changing the value and comparing after, so the condition was only triggered once.